# Align image slider at the same bottom using css (Slick Carousel library)

Tags: html, css, slick.js

im using slick carousel library to create a sublime slider, but using images widh a different height didn't make images aligned at the same bottom :

[image]

my code :

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>slick - the last carousel you'll ever need</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="slider responsive">
        <div><img src="http://url/Public/Publications/856518/1916982/Images/Detail.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="http://url/Public/Publications/101506/1917549/Images/Detail.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="http://url/Public/Publications/678542/1917100/Images/Detail.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="http://url/Public/Publications/1658142/1917547/Images/Detail.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="http://cdn1.lekiosk.com/Public/Publications/596057/1911177/Images/Detail.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="http://url/Public/Publications/286869/1917506/Images/Detail.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="http://url/Public/Publications/678542/1917100/Images/Detail.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="http://url/Public/Publications/856518/1916982/Images/Detail.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".responsive").not('.slick-initialized').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    arrows: false,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 2,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 5,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: true,
            arrows: false,
            dots: false
        }
    }, {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
            arrows: false,
            dots: false,
            infinite: true
        }
    }, {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            arrows: false,
            infinite: true,
            dots: false
        }
    }]
});
</script>

</html>
```

i don't want to put height value for each screen resolution using media queries.
Any idea please ?

Comment: add a `row` then specify the columns a.k.a. `col` with Bootstrap, that should fix it. If not, please provide some code so I can look into it.

Comment: @ZombieChowder please see my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to your problem. I wouldn't say it's the best one but it does the job. So the thing you could actually do is reference each image separately with the css rule of `max-height`. I specified that each image should have `style ="max-height:300px;"` which gets them to the same height. Here is how I changed your code:

```
    <div class="slider responsive">
        <div><img src="http://cdn1.lekiosk.com/Public/Publications/856518/1916982/Images/Detail.jpg"style ="max-height:300px;"></div>
        <div><img src="http://cdn1.lekiosk.com/Public/Publications/101506/1917549/Images/Detail.jpg" style ="max-height:300px;"></div>
        <div><img src="http://cdn1.lekiosk.com/Public/Publications/678542/1917100/Images/Detail.jpg"style ="max-height:300px;"></div>
        <div><img src="http://cdn1.lekiosk.com/Public/Publications/1658142/1917547/Images/Detail.jpg" style ="max-height:300px;"></div>
        <div><img src="http://cdn1.lekiosk.com/Public/Publications/596057/1911177/Images/Detail.jpg" style ="max-height:300px;"></div>
        <div><img src="http://cdn1.lekiosk.com/Public/Publications/286869/1917506/Images/Detail.jpg" style ="max-height:300px;"></div>
        <div><img src="http://cdn1.lekiosk.com/Public/Publications/678542/1917100/Images/Detail.jpg" style ="max-height:300px;"></div>
        <div><img src="http://cdn1.lekiosk.com/Public/Publications/856518/1916982/Images/Detail.jpg" style ="max-height:300px;"></div>
    </div>
```

Here's a carousel slider with Bootstrap where all the images are the same height. Feel free to check it out:

[Carousel Slider Bootstrap](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26456/)

It's not the most elegant solution but it does the job. Tell me if it worked for you.

[New Fiddle #2](https://jsfiddle.net/svwhn2g7/1/)

Comment: @AHmédNet I've added a JS Fiddle, check it out and say if that is ok.

Comment: no the same issue if you use this image picture (one time) http://cdn1.lekiosk.com/Public/Publications/101506/1917549/Images/Detail.jpg

Comment: @AHmédNet I just used the same picture because it was more convenient, plus you deleted the other ones. I really don't know how this solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: try to use different images with multiple height, Thank's for your time (y)

Comment: @AHmédNet ok, I edited my answer and check out Fiddle #2

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to align all picture in the same line :

Container : display : flex;
items :     align-self: flex-end;

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a `max-height`/`height` property on your images.
Or alternatively, you can create 2 separate divs: One the image row, and one the text row. Then, the text row would be aligned together and the images would be aligned together.
Sync the carousels: *(This is an example for slick's website)*

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true
});
```